# How to secure uBlogsy against script injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I have an umbraco 4.11 site with uBlogsy 2.1.1.2 installed.
Everything works fine, except I can't seem to protect myself against script injection through the comment form.

I've turned on

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="true" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and it does throw the expected error. "A potentially dangerous request.form..."
but the post is also submitted. Which is NOT OK!

Are there alternative ways to block this through a regularexpressionvalidator or so?

Comment: I didn't find a solution, so I threw out the comment form and replaced it with disqus.